# Error in loading in Cosmos through Spark job due to Bulk Upsert

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-databricks

Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 8 in stage 9387.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 8.3 in stage 9387.0 (TID 715923, 10.0.132.79, executor 2):
Errors encountered in bulk import API execution.

Record size are way too less than 2MB.
Job run is from Data bricks notebook.

Comment: The destination collection has well defined partition key as well.

Comment: Can you please post more details about the errors? Are you using one of the Spark Connectors? Which version?

Comment: @Matias  I am running my Pyspark job from Databricks. DBR Runtime version is 6.4 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11) From the Cosmos side, the table is in SQL API.

Comment: Can you add more of the error details? The error text seems to be coming from https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark, are you using that package? If so, which version?